# How to detect if document.write() has taken place in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something when 2 document.write() statements have successfully occured. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
        function loadFields() {
            var load1 = document.write("<input type='text' name='StoreLocation' value='"+storeLocation+"' />");
            var load2 = document.write("<input type='text' name='couponType' value='"+couponType+"' />");
        }

        if (loadFields()) {
            alert('both items have loaded.');
        }
```

I also tried this and again same result:

```
        var load1 = document.write("<input type='text' name='StoreLocation' value='"+storeLocation+"' />");
        var load2 = document.write("<input type='text' name='couponType' value='"+couponType+"' />");

        if (load1 && load2) {
            alert('both items have loaded.');
        }
```

Comment: You already have your answer, but next time you say "didn't work" you might want to specify what happened and how that differed from what you hoped would happen.

Comment: I just wounder, Does it appear like it has not happen before you click away the alert? If so, what browser does you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function loadFields() {
        document.write("<input type='text' name='StoreLocation' value='"+storeLocation+"' />");
        document.write("<input type='text' name='couponType' value='"+couponType+"' />");
        return true;
    }

    if (loadFields()) {
        alert('both items have loaded.');
    }
```

OR

```
    function loadFields() {
        document.write("<input id='StoreLocation' type='text' name='StoreLocation' value='"+storeLocation+"' />");
        document.write("<input id='cuponType' type='text' name='couponType' value='"+couponType+"' />");
    }

    if (document.getElementById("StoreLocation") && document.getElementById("cuponType")) {
        alert('both items have loaded.');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in what you're trying to do. document.write happens as soon as the code is encountered, so on the next line after document.write, the text has already been added into the document.

Answer (score 0):

The document.write calls are not asynchronous, meaning that they have taken place when any code after them are executed.

```
// It has not happen yet as of this point.
var load1 = document.write("<input type='text' name='StoreLocation' value='"+storeLocation+"' />");
var load2 = document.write("<input type='text' name='couponType' value='"+couponType+"' />");
// Now it has happen, as of this point.
```